# How can I change the keyboard layout through the terminal?

Tags: macos, keyboard, ruby

This is necessary, because I write the program on Ruby, and I need to programmatically change the layout of the keyboard

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution using the [xkbswitch](https://github.com/myshov/xkbswitch-macosx) utility.